# How to read Http port in c#?

Tags: c#

how can we read http port in c#

Comment: Please give more background.. do you wish to download a file from a website or what?

Comment: Please, try to be more specific. Are you using ASP.NET and you want to know on which port the website is running? Do you want to read data from port 80 in a desktop application? When doing question try to write all the useful things that could help us to answer.

Comment: i am using windows application and I want to know which site is open on my browser thats why i want to read http port(8080).....is there is alternate way to know how which site is open on my browser?

Comment: Note that if the website is not currently *loading* in your browser, the HTTP port will not be open and you won't be able to tell anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given the lack of detail in the question, here is a broad spectrum dose answer

If you want to write an HTTP Server you can

1. Use [HttpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx)
2. Use [TcpLister](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx) class and write your own TCP server
3. Use the [Socket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx) class and write your own TCP server

If your intention is to monitor the HTTP traffic that your server is receiving then you can

1. Use WinPCap ([SharpPCap](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/sharppcap/index.php?title=Main_Page)) to capture the traffic and filter the traffic you are interested in

If your intention is to send HTTP traffic to a server

1. Look at [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) class
2. Loot at [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class

Comment: That's a really broad set of options but very informative as to all the ways this can be accomplished.